# Cookies not being set on iOS using identityserver

Tags: ios, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a mobile app that is using ODIC authorization code flow. Our server implementation is using Identity Server 4.

The mobile app opens a browser window and I can login to a 3rd party provider just fine, it then redirects to `/signin-adfs` on our identity server, which sets some `idsrv.external` cookies and returns a 302 to `/External/Callback`. The browser redirects to `/External/Callback` but doesn't send any of the `idsrv.external` cookies with it so Identity Server throws an exception because the result from `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync` is not successful.

I'm kind of stuck at this point because I'm not a mobile developer. I deployed and have customized Identity Server slightly in other areas but not this part of the code.

I believe the mobile app is opening a Safari session to do the auth. Is this an issue with the cookies that the browser doesn't like (domain, path, https, secure)? or something else? The cookie size is chunked to 4KB a piece. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

To make things even weirder... if the browser is refreshed (`/External/Callback`) then the request works and the iOS app gets the code and can make the follow up request to get the token.

Comment: You can check what is in the cookie. Check `NSHTTPCookieStorage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was digging through the IS4 source and saw a link to [this issue on github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2595). Looks like it was fixed in source but hasn't been released yet. There are some workarounds in the github issue if you need it sooner than the release. The problem is specific to iOS 12.